# Batch Find and Replace in PDF

Tags: macos, pdf

I am trying to do a batch find and replace operating in PDF files. Goal is to search for SKUs in a supplier's catalog and replace it with our sales price. Result does not have to look nice, as long as it works 95% of the time.

For instance looking for `PRODUCT9522` and replacing it with `PRODUCT9522 - 95.20E`.

I tried several options, like uncompressing the PDF with `pdftk` and then searching and replacing with `sed`, but that did not work. Some GUI tools did work to some extent, but not exactly like I wanted them to.

I would really appreciate your expertise on this matter.

I would like to do this on a Mac using OS X

Comment: Does this answer your query?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246285/how-to-find-and-replace-in-a-pdf-on-os-x?rq=1

Comment: @ankiiiiiii OP is looking for a batch solution, the answers on the linked questions are more for interactive use.

Comment: @nohillside Acrobat forums concluded on PDF not being an heavily editable file format. As the gold standard says so, I thought I should add it here. Also, OP didn't mention which GUI they already tried.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Fair point. Let's put it on hold as a duplicate for now. Florian, if you can be more specific about why this isn't a duplicate please edit it into the question.

Comment: PDFPen Pro is scriptable, and has good batch processing capabilities. Simply editing the PDF data itself with a text editor or grep tool is going to bring horrors.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I have tried PDFPen, which supports Applescript, but I could not get it to work for search and replace text. There are no details in PDFPen's user's manual concerning that, and I only found a script example to redact text, which works, but I could not modify it to search and replace.
This is too complicated for me I believe, sadly :(
Search and replace in the menu works, and that was very promising...